# web analytics web service and data processing service in farm

Tags: web, farm

- I have 4 wfe and 2 app servers in my farm.
- There is only one publishing portal on this farm.
- I provisioned the web analytics service application through central admin.

Now i want to start the "**Web Analytics Data Processing Service**"  and "**Web Analytics Web Service**". Should i start those two services **in which servers**? **App servers** or **Web Front Ends** or all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Most architects I know would use their last WFE for something like this, the one that gets hit the least and make it a fail over WFE.

Or ideally have a Server for things like this.